# Restrict that only one element has a specific attribute with DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

This is the xml file that I need to validate with DTD:

```
<branch state="hessen">
    <city>Marburg</city>
    <headquarter/>
    <staff manager="yes">Egon</staff>
    <staff manager="no">Erna</staff>
    <staff manager="no">Claudia</staff>
</branch>
```

The problem is that only one manager is allowed per branch. The task is now to restrict that with a DTD file but I dont now how to do that.

This is what I've got so far:

```
 <!ELEMENT insurance (branch*)>
            <!ELEMENT branch (city,zentrale?,(staff,staff+))>
            <!ATTLIST branch
                    state ID #REQUIRED
            >
            <!ELEMENT city (#PCDATA)>
            <!ELEMENT headquarter EMPTY>
            <!ELEMENT staff (#PCDATA)>
            <!ATTLIST staff
                    manager (yes|no) #REQUIRED
            >
```

How can I now implement that restriction?

Comment: You won’t be able to enforce that rule with a DTD.

Comment: Mhmm okay ;/ do you know how I could do it then ?

Comment: You could also do it using XSD (XML Schema) version 1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won’t be able to enforce that rule with a DTD.

I agree with Michael Kay's suggestion of using XML Schema 1.1.

You can use [`xs:assert`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) to enforce the rule.

Example...

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <xs:element name="branch">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="headquarter"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="staff"/>        
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="state" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
      <xs:assert test="count(staff[@manager='yes']) le 1"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:NCName"/>

  <xs:element name="headquarter">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="staff">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:NCName">
          <xs:attribute name="manager" use="required" type="xs:NCName"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

You could also use [Schematron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schematron) or XSLT to do the rule checking.